# SAS Code for Counts by Group for a Large Dataset

Tags: sql, performance, group-by, count, sas

I'm looking for an efficient way to produce sums by week ('weekstart') as a variable ('weekcount') within a dataset of tens of millions of rows. I need it as a variable for further analysis later on, before reducing the dataset. The code below takes too long to run and had to terminate, so I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way of producing these group sums for later use.

```
proc sql;
select weekstart, count(*) as Weekcount
from pharm
group by weekstart
order by weekstart;
quit;
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried a PROC MEANS or FREQ? They're typically more resource efficient.

Comment: Is the dataset already sorted by weekstart? Is there an index?

Comment: try to add noprint option after `proc sql` and add `create table want as` to export the query result to a dataset other than the result window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a hash object to compute bin frequency when a very large table is not being processed efficiently by `Proc FREQ` or `Proc SQL`.

```
data have;
  call streaminit(20230420);

  do _n_ = 1 to 2e6;
    pid = rand('integer', 1, 2.5e5);
    weekstart = intnx ('week', '01jan2015'd + rand('integer', 1, 2500), 1);
    output;
  end;
  format weekstart yymmdd10.;
run;

data weekstart_freq;
  weekstart = 0;

  declare hash bins(ordered:'a', suminc:'_n_');
  bins.defineKey('weekstart');
  bins.defineDone();

  do while (not lastrow);
    set have(keep=weekstart) end=lastrow;
    bins.ref(); /* perform bin counting via suminc var */
  end;

  declare hiter foreachbin('bins');

  do while (0=foreachbin.next());
    bins.sum(sum:freq);  /* retrieve bin count */
    output;
  end;

  stop;
run;
```

Here is a similar alternative that uses the `HASH` `keysum:` argument to make the `freq` variable automatically part of the `.output ()` data set

```
data _null_ ;
  weekstart = 0;

  declare hash bins(ordered:'a', suminc:'_n_', keysum:'freq');
  bins.defineKey('weekstart');
  bins.defineDone();
  retain freq 0 ;

  do while (not lastrow);
    set have(keep=weekstart) end=lastrow;
    bins.ref(); /* perform bin counting (freq accumulation) via suminc var */
  end ;

  bins.output(dataset:'weekstart_freq2') ;
  stop ;
run ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `proc hpsummary` if you have High Peformance PROCs available. `hpsummary` scales well with big data.

```
proc hpsummary data=pharm;
    class weekstart;
    output out=counts;
quit;

proc sort data=counts;
    by weekstart;
run;
```